# Looping through an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through different data on the same view, sometimes the data looks like this:

```
[{"id":"3","title":"Collection C","short_title":"CC","looks":[{"id":"6","title":"Look 6","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":null,"published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"3","look_id":"6"}},{"id":"7","title":"Look 7","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"1","published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"3","look_id":"7"}}]},{"id":"1","title":"Collection A","short_title":"CA","looks":[{"id":"2","title":"Look 2","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"0","published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"1","look_id":"2"}}]}]
```

And other times it looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","title":"Collection A","thumb":null,"banner":null,"video":"ftfgf","looks":[{"id":"2","title":"Look 2","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"0","published":"1","url":"test","pivot":{"collection_id":"1","look_id":"2"}}]} BESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswy
```

The second set of data breaks my loop, is this becuase it's not in an array itself, if so, how can I put it into an array so it's the only element.

Or is there a better way to tackle the problem?

Comment: Are you decoding the JSON prior to looping? What should the end-result be? Posting the expected output (along with your code) might help you get *more* accurate answers.

Answer (score 3):

That's JSON, not an array. Use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to turn it into an object or an array (by passing `true` as the second parameter). Then iterating through it will be simple.

From the manual:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
The above example will output:

object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```